# In tensorflow federated, how to assign different training functions to different clients?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

The low-level function `tff.federated_mean(tff.federated_map(fn, data))` assigns the same training function to all of the clients.

Is there any way to assign different training functions to the clients?

Answer (score 1):

TFF is not really designed to allow for addressing clients in different groups. This is by design, since generally in federated learning one should treat groups of clients as single objects. Opening the door to treat different clients differently seems to lead down the road of collecting individual observations, running counter to the philosophy of "everything in aggregate".

However, this does not mean that this desire is unsupported in TFF. There are a few options here.

First, it is worthwhile noting that when you are writing TFF, you are generally writing at three distinct levels. You are writing pure TensorFlow to express individual units of computation, e.g. what each client is going to do, or a custom aggregation function. You are writing "native TFF" for lack of a better term to express orchestration logic, wiring these units of computation together. Examples of this include your calls to `federated_map` and `federated_mean` above. Finally, you are writing Python to drive your experiment. An example of this is passing a Python list to a computation which accepts a federated value at CLIENTS.

Given this, one way to write a TFF computation which treats two groups of clients differently is simply to write two different TFF computations and call them on these distinct groups. That is, you can keep the groups split at the *python* level, so that the TFF is unaware of the need to separate these groups of clients.

Another option that may be useful to highlight is to *allow the clients to select the computation they wish to run*. An example of this would be the following `tf_computation`:

```py
@tff.tf_computation(tf.int32)
def foo(x):
  if x > 0:
    return bar(x)
  return baz(x)
```

where `bar` and `baz` are also instances of `tf_computation`.

This computation can then be applied via `federated_map` to a single group of clients.

This option can be somewhat married with the first if you model the groups of clients as including an indicator bit, so that instead of a list of `tf.data.Dataset`s representing datasets placed at CLIENTS, this is represented as a list of tuples whose first element is a dataset and second is an int allowing for the clients to determine which "group" they are in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Absolutely, way 1 and way 2  can work.  When I try to implement way 1, I have another question " How to keep the groups split at the python level" except including an indictor bit.

Comment: I simply meant here to keep two different lists around in Python, then pass them into the two distinct computations separately